# Change size of event title on wordpress front end info page

Tags: css

I found this
[image]

and tried this #crm-container .crm-title h1 {
font-size: 8px;
margin: 0;
padding: 4px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
}
into [civicrm.files]/css/extra.css
but I dont really know what I'm doing!

Comment: h1 or h2? Also is your background dark since if it's light then color fff will make the text mostly invisible.

Comment: I'd quite like it to disappear. I'd just like someone who knows css to give me the right syntax. Mine didn't have any affect so I think the css elements are wrong

Answer (score 1):

If as per comments you just want it to disappear: `#crm-container .crm-title h2 { display: none; }`

But note extras.css was removed years ago. You'll need to add that css [in an extension](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/resources/#css-stylesheets) or you can add a custom css file at administer - system settings - resource urls, or you can add it in your front-end theme.

Comment: Thanks I thought extra.css was a custom css file. Resource url is as above. So either path is wrong or css is incorrect. I tried your css - also no effect.

Comment: When you say as above I assume you mean `[civicrm.files]/css/extra.css` - are you aware `[civicrm.files]` points to `sites/default/files/civicrm` (e.g. on drupal), not /path/to/the/civicrm/code/files? If you click the help icon in the intro at the top of Administer - System Settings - Resource Urls it will tell you the url it thinks it corresponds to.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks demerit! - it was a res. Url issue.
I changed to absolute path https://xxxx.org.au/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/css/extras.css

and it worked.